# Inserting a record with a Composite Key using NHibernate fails

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am trying to reference some child entities with part of the parents composite id.
I have a table defnition as given below:

```
Programs
Events
ProgramEvents
```

Class Files:

```
public class Program
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ProgramEvent> StartEvents { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ProgramEvent> EndEvents { get; set; }
}

public class ProgramEvent
{
    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Repeatable { get; set; }
    public virtual int EventOrder { get; set; }
    public virtual int EventSection { get; set; }
    public virtual Program Program { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as ProgramEvent);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = GetType().GetHashCode();

            hash = (hash * 31) ^ EventSection.GetHashCode();
            hash = (hash * 31) ^ EventOrder.GetHashCode();
            hash = (hash * 31) ^ Event.Id.GetHashCode();
            hash = (hash * 31) ^ Program.Id.GetHashCode();

            return hash;
        }
    }
```

Mapping for the program class contains such reference:

```
<list name="StartEvents" table="ProgramEvents" lazy="false" where="EVENT_SECTION = 1" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true">
  <key column="PROGRAM_ID" />
  <index column="EVENT_ORDER" />
  <one-to-many class="ProgramEvent"/>
</list>
```

Mapping for the program event class:

```
  <class name="ProgramEvent" table="ProgramEvents">

    <composite-id>
      <key-many-to-one class="Program"  lazy="false" name="Program" column="PROGRAM_ID" />
      <key-many-to-one class="Event"  lazy="false" name="Event" column="EVENT_ID" />
      <key-property name="EventOrder" column="EVENT_ORDER" />
      <key-property name="EventSection" column="EVENT_SECTION" />
    </composite-id>

    <property name="Repeatable" column="REPEATABLE"/>

  </class>
```

When I try to save program with new reference to the events table I got such error:

> SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PROGRAM_ID',
>   table 'ProgramEvents'; column does not allow nulls.
>   INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

I open the sql profiler and got such sql:

> exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO ProgramEvents (REPEATABLE,
>   PROGRAM_ID, EVENT_ID, EVENT_ORDER, EVENT_SECTION) VALUES (@p0, @p1,
>   @p2, @p3, @p4)',N'@p0 bit,@p1 int,@p2 int,@p3 int,@p4
>   int',@p0=1,@p1=NULL,@p2=NULL,@p3=0,@p4=0

The NHibernate really try to insert null values. Why it happens?

**UPD**
I try to update the program like this:

```
    var program = ProgramDao.Current.GetById(1);

    var newEvent = EventDao.Current.GetById(4);
    var programEvent = new ProgramEvent { Event = newEvent, Repeatable = true };
    program.StartEvents.Add(programEvent);

    using (var session = SessionFactory.Current.OpenSession())
    {
        session.Evict(program);
        session.Update(program);
        session.Flush();
    }
```

Comment: It does not help.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
public class ClassNameMap: ClassMap<ClassName>
{
    public ClassNameMap()
    {
        CompositeId().
            .KeyReference(x => x.A, "A")
            .KeyReference(x => x.B, "B");
    }
}
```

Comment: But I already have composite-id declaration in the ProgramEvent mapping file.

Answer (score 0):

You must set programEvent.Program to point to the program. As you specify inverse=true, it is the responsibility of the contained class to maintain the reference to Program.

Also, I would avoid evict and update. Should not be necessary in common program structures. But your example code is weird... you should load the Program instance and do your changes inside of one single session. (This is not required. There are code structures that does it otherwise, but unless you are absolute sure you must do it another way, it's generally far easier to perform load, modify and persist (flush) inside a single session. You really(!) should also open a transaction to ensure reliable operation.

Comment: I already try to set programEvent.Program but it doesn`t help. It seems that nhibernate just ignore all values in my model during insert. By the way the update operation doing well. This is the code just for example and I use it my unit test.